# Sending a message with name of current page in one click

Tags: php, html, email, joomla, message

I have a site that contain more than 10000 videos, and sometimes there is embeded video that doesnt work, i need to show to my visitors this message "click here if the video doesnt show anymore" and when they click to this message , i will recieve a notification from the page that has been clicked

I didnt found any joomla extension that can do this

If i put this php code in every page of my joomla website

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Send details to embassy" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

It will send me a message in one click.

How can i receive a mail containing the name of page where the user has clicked?

In Joomla with this html code we can obtain the name of the current page.

```
<? $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
echo $doc->getTitle();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$message = 'Page:' . $doc->getTitle();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I Tried it again and It really Worked, thank you for help bro